# How to get jar name in start.sh script

Tags: shell, sh

I am deploying a spring boot app + maven. I have   written a start.sh script using link https://dzone.com/articles/packaging-springboot-application-with-external-dep

The jar name can change as per the version , so I don't want to hard code the jar name in start.sh like  **-jar ../lib/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar**

How can I  make it dependent on jar name? any variable substitution possible?

Comment: Use shell expansion:  `-jar ../lib/gs-spring-boot-*.jar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know there's only one JAR file, how about something like this

```
JAR_FILE=`ls ../lib/gs-spring-boot-*.jar`
java -jar ${JAR_FILE}
```

Comment: or `ls <dirPath> | grep <namePattern>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your start.sh script automatically and paste correct jar name there. Please check http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/

Examples: http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-program.html

In combination with maven-assembly you can create a tar.gz or zip archive which contains everything that you need.

Comment: This.  Don't handwrite the shell wrappers.

Comment: Using appassembler for a spring boot application is not a good idea..cause it will much more than needed...

Comment: @khmarbaise Only if you ask it to.  The automation of the shell wrappers is quite valuable.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I know how appassembler works cause I'm one of the maintainers...but I wouldn't recommend it for this purpose...

Comment: @khmarbaise My personal opinion is that as Java has not yet found a good way to distribute single-jar deployments across platforms (an embedded icon and a jar-in-jar classloader is pretty much what is needed) launcher scripts are needed but should _not_ be handwritten.  To my knowledge the only launch script generator is appassembler so it should be used even if just for that.  That aside, please write a better answer so OP can choose what is best.